# Conditional Dropdown for Shopify cart checkout

Tags: if-statement, drop-down-menu, conditional-statements, switch-statement, shopify

This is all for a Shopify shopping cart check out page.

I am attempting to create a color choice selection in a conditional dropdown series. Where if in the first dropdown you select "Random" color choice a message will appear that says "Thank you a Random color choice will be selected for you".

Or

If you select one of the color brands a second dropdown box will appear that the customer will need to select the color number associated with the color they want.

Below is as far as I have figured out. I am not getting the conditional statement correct. Any help in this would be aswesome.

```
   <p class="line-item-property__field">
        <label>Color Wheel</label><br>
            <select required class="required" id="color.wheel" name="properties[Color Wheel]">
            <option value="Random">Random</option>
            <option value="Amolen">Amolen</option>
            <option value="Stronghro3D">Stronghro3D</option>
            <option value="PolyMaker">PolyMaker</option>
            <option value="CookieCad">CookieCad</option>
            <option value="Zyltech">Zyltech</option>
            <option value="Ziro 3D">Ziro 3D</option>
        </select>
       
        {% case color.wheel %}
          {% when 'Random' %}
              Thank you a Random Color will be selected for you
          {% when 'Amolen' %}
                <select required class="required" id="amolen.color" name="properties[Amolen Color]">
                <option value="AM-0001">AM-0001</option>
                <option value="AM-0002">AM-0002</option>
                <option value="AM-0003">AM-0003</option>
                <option value="AM-0004">AM-0004</option>
                <option value="AM-0005">AM-0005</option>
                <option value="AM-0006">AM-0006</option>
                 <option value="AM-0007">AM-0007</option>
                </select>
      {% else %}
       Error
    {% endcase %}
    </p>
```

What I am expect is to have one dropdown visible to start with then depending upon the selection in that drop down either my message or a second drop down with the correct information in it will appear.

Comment: Check Shopify documentation for Line Item Properties. That is how you do this. Use that, and you will have all your colors recorded properly.

Comment: I did this and what I am looking for isn't in that documentation

Comment: It is absolutely, 100% the way to go. You want to capture a color. It makes no sense outside the context of a product. So unless you are using "a shopping experience" as a context, line item properties are the way to go. But hey, you be you!

Comment: You do not understand what it is that I am trying to do. If that was the route I wanted to go I would have taken it but that isn't what I want to do, because what it is that I am selling I have way too many color options. what I want is more along the lines of a Cascading Dropdown which isn't part of the properties or attributes standards given. and it have to be done at the checkout

Comment: So just capture your color as a cart attribute and you're good to go. Fine.

Comment: that is what I am trying to do but my code isn't working and why I am seeking help. Each brand has several color choices. I have a page where they can see all the different brands and color choices. So I want once the brand is picked a second drop-down appears with the option to pick the number that goes with that brand.